# Elastic search DSL python issue

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have been using the ElasticSearch DSL python package to query my elastic search database. The querying method is very intuitive but I'm having issues retrieving the documents. This is what I have tried:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{"host":'xyz', "port":9200}],timeout=400)
s = Search(using=es,index ="xyz-*").query("match_all")
response = s.execute()
for hit in response:
    print hit.title
```

The error I get :

```
AttributeError: 'Hit' object has no attribute 'title'
```

I googled the error and found another SO : [How to access the response object using elasticsearch DSL for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836490/how-to-access-the-response-object-using-elasticsearch-dsl-for-python)

The solution mentions:

```
for hit in response:
     print hit.doc.firstColumnName
```

Unfortunately, I had the same issue again with 'doc'. I was wondering what the correct way to access my document was?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: you can print(s.to_dict()) and print(response.to_dict()) to look into the objects

Comment: Thanks! That did work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issues as I've found different versions of this, but it seems to depend on the version of the elasticsearch-dsl library you're using.  You might explore the `response` object, and it's sub-objects.  For instance, using version 5.3.0, I see the expected data using the below loop.

```
for hit in RESPONSE.hits._l_:
    print(hit)
```

or

```
for hit in RESPONSE.hits.hits:
    print(hit)
```

NOTE these are limited to 10 data elements for some strange reason.

```
print(len(RESPONSE.hits.hits))
10
print(len(RESPONSE.hits._l_))
10
```

This doesn't match the amount of overall hits if I print the number of hits using `print('Total {} hits found.\n'.format(RESPONSE.hits.total))`

Good luck!

Comment: 10 hits because you are not providing the size parameter in the query. 10 is the default size.

Answer (score 0):

From version 6 onwards the response does not return your populated Document class anymore, meaning that your fields are just an `AttrDict` which is basically a dictionary.

To solve this you need to have a `Document` class representing the document you want to parse. Then you need to parse the hit dictionary with your document class using the `.from_es()` method.

Like I answered here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64169419/5144029

Also have a look at the `Document` class here

https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/7.3.0/persistence.html