# How to convert a Hit into a Document with elasticsearch-dsl?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

Consider the following mapping for a document in ES.

```
class MyDoc(elasticseach_dsl.Document):
    id_info = Object(IdInfo)

class IdInfo(elasticseach_dsl.InnerDoc):
    id = Keyword()
    type = Keyword()
```

Using elasticsearch-dsl, there are 2 ways of retrieving a document (that I am interested in):

- Using `MyDoc.search().query().execute()`, that yields `Hit` objects
- Using `MyDoc.get()`, that yields a `MyDoc` object

Here is the issue I am experiencing:

When I retrieve the same document from ES, and that document is missing, for example, the `type` field, I get different behaviours:

- When using `search()`: `doc` being a `Hit` object, accessing `doc.type` raises a `KeyError`
- When using `get()`: `doc` being a `MyDoc` object, accessing `doc.type` simply returns `None`

To workaround this discrepancy, I would like to convert a `Hit` instance to a `MyDoc` instance, so that I can always use the `doc.type` syntax without any errors being raised.

How can I do that?

Alternatively, is there a way that I could access `Hit` instances with the same behaviour as `MyDoc` instances?

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_hit = hit.to_dict()
doc = YourDocument(**dict_hit)
doc.property1 # you can access the property here
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit awkward and annoying, it used to work with versions below 6.

I found a workaround, if you take the dictionary coming out from elasticsearch response you can then ask the document class to interpret it like the following.

```py
query = MyDoc.search()

response = query.execute()

my_doc = MyDoc.from_es(response.hits.hits[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

We were facing this situation. In our case, is was due to the index name in the `Index` subclass to configure Document indices. Our model looked more or les like this:

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    my_field = Keyword()

    class Index:
       name = "my-doc-v1-*"
```

This way, when querying for documents in indexes that match that name (for example "my-doc-v1-2022-07"), hits are automatically instantianted as `MyDoc` objects.
Now we have started to generate 'v2' indices, named like "my-doc-v2--000001", and then hits were not being populated as `MyDoc` objects.
For that to happen, we had to change `Index.name` to `my-doc-*`. That way, documents from both 'v1' and 'v2' indices are always populated automatically by the library, since they match the `Index.name` expression.

Comment: You can do the by overriding the classmethod `_matches(cls, hit)`. The class method returning something like `hit["_index"] == 'my-doc-v1' or fnmatch(hit["_index"], "my-doc-v1-*")` should do that.